Conditions equivalent to the ε-N definition
I want to know the condition equivalent to the ε-N definition. I think TFAE. But, I can't prove [2. ⟹ 1.].
$(a_n)$ is a sequence such that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N},a_n\in \mathbb{R}$,and $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ is real interval

$\forall \varepsilon>0,\ \exists N\in \mathbb{N},\ n\geq N \implies |a_n-a|<\varepsilon$
($\exists I\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $I$ is a real interval and $\ \exists m>0,\ \forall y\in (0,m),\ I\cap (0,y)\neq \emptyset$$ \exists G:I\to \mathbb{R},G \ \text{is a function}\ ,  G(x)\to 0(x\to 0)),\ \\ \forall \varepsilon\in I\cap \mathbb{R}_{>0},\ \exists N\in \mathbb{N},\ n\geq N \implies |a_n-a|<G(\varepsilon)$

Is this true? If this is true, how to prove this 2⇒1?
The condition [$\exists m>0,\ \forall y\in (0,m),\ I\cap (0,y)\neq \emptyset$] means that [$G$ is a function that does not need to be defined at $0$, but is defined for sufficiently small all positive values close to $0$] .
For example, $G=\frac{x^3}{x(x-1)}$. This function $G$ is defined on $(0,1)$ and $G\to 0 (x\to 0)$.
For example, in 2 I am considering the following situation:
$\forall \varepsilon\in (0,1),\ \exists N\in \mathbb{N},\ n\geq N \implies |a_n-a|<\frac{\varepsilon^3}{\varepsilon(\varepsilon-1)}$
The proof of 1⇒2 is easy. ($G(x)=x,\ I=\mathbb{R}$)

I'm sorry.  I used abbreviations that are often used in lectures, thinking that it might be difficult to read if there were too many characters.

I have rewritten it in more detail and added examples of the situations I am considering

The example example makes it much clearer what you are trying to show. However, I don't understand why you have introduced so many elements. Could the condition not just be that there exists $m>0$ and $G:(0,m)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $G(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, and for all $\epsilon \in (0,m)$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have $|a_n - a| < G(\epsilon)$? I guess I am asking why you are introducing two separate intervals, $I$ and $(0,m)$?

@NaturalLogZ You are right. My way of expressing things was unclear. Thank you for your comments.


Are you really requiring $I$ to be an interval or just a set? 2) Anyway, our condition  $$\exists m>0,\ \forall y\in (0,m),\ I\cap (y,m)\neq \emptyset
$$
is not sufficient for $I$ to contain points arbitrarily close to $0$ (a counterexample is $I=(1,2)$ and $m=2$), so $\lim_{x\to0}G(x)=0$ makes no sense.


@AnneBauval thank you for your comment. I made a mistake. The correct one is $(0,y)$, not $(y,m)$.

This answers my 2), but what about my 1)? I think you only require $I$ to be a set, because for an interval, your condition $\exists m>0,,\forall y\in (0,m),\ I\cap (0,y)\neq \emptyset$ is equivalent to $\exists a>0;(0,a)\subset I$.

I think condition $2.$ means $\exists$ set $I$, such that $\forall x>0$, $I\cap (0,x)\neq\emptyset$, $\exists$ function $G:I\to \mathbb{R}$, such that $G(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, and $\forall \varepsilon \in I \cap (0,\infty)$, $\exists N,$ $n\geq N\implies |a_n - a| < G(\varepsilon).$
The condition $\forall x>0$, $I\cap (0,x)\neq\emptyset$ says $I$ contains non-zero elements arbitrarily close to $0$.
It this is correct, then $2. \implies 1.$
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.
Pick $\varepsilon’\in I\cap(0,\infty)$ such that $G(\varepsilon’)<\varepsilon$. Using $G(x)\to 0$.
Pick $N$ such that $n\geq N\implies |a_n - a| < G(\varepsilon’).$ Then $n\geq N\implies |a_n - a| < \varepsilon.$ Using $G(\varepsilon’)<\varepsilon$.

The question was edited while I was typing, hope my attempt at an answer still makes sense.

Thank you for your comment. From the condition [$G(x)\to 0$] , I can pick up such $\varepsilon'$ !  I didn't realize that. thank you.
